# java jackson parse object containing a generic type object

Tags: java, json, parsing, generics, jackson

i have the following problem.

I have to parse a json request into an object that contains a generic type field.

**EDIT**

i have made some tests using a regular class type (so i make it work before i replace it with generic). Now parsing for a single element works great.

The issue is when i need to parse out a list object out of that class.

So i have to inform jackson somehow that my T is of type list instead of just AlbumModel.

Here is what i have tried.

```
 @Override
    public ListResponseModel<AlbumModel> parse(String responseBody) throws Exception {
    JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseModel.class,
        AlbumModel.class);
    return mapper.readValue(responseBody,
        mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseModel.class, type));
    }
```

But the code above doesn't work. what is the solution for something like this?

my generic type in the ListResponseModel is defined like: `List<T> data`

succeeded like:

```
public class BaseResponseModel<T> {

    @JsonProperty("data")
    private T data;

    @JsonProperty("paginations")
    private PaginationModel pagination;
}
```

so far i have the following code but it always parses into a Hash.

```
public class ResponseParser extends BaseJacksonMapperResponseParser<ResponseModel<AlbumModel>> {

    public static final String TAG = ResponseParser.class.getSimpleName();

    @Override
    public ResponseModel<AlbumModel> parse(String responseBody) throws Exception {
        return mapper.readValue(responseBody,
                mapper.getTypeFactory().constructParametricType(ResponseModel.class, AlbumModel.class));
    }
}

public abstract class BaseJacksonMapperResponseParser<T> implements HttpResponseParser<T> {

    public static final String TAG = BaseJacksonMapperResponseParser.class.getSimpleName();

    public static ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    static {
        mapper.disable(Feature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES);
        mapper.enable(Feature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT);
        mapper.configure(SerializationConfig.Feature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree with eugen's answer but just wanted to expand on it a bit.  The first step is to refactor your parse method so it takes a second argument.  Instead of allocating the type reference in your method, you require the caller to pass in a TypeReference instance.

```
public BaseResponseModel<T> parse(String responseBody, TypeReference<T> ref) throws Exception {
    return mapper.readValue(responseBody, ref);
}
```

Unfortunately your snippet does not show the code which calls parse - so I'll make something up:

```
BaseResponseParser<Collection<Person>> parser = new BaseResponseParser<Collection<Person>>();
BaseResponseModel<Collection<Person>> result = parser.parse(jsonText, new TypeReference<Collection<Person>>(){});
```

Notice that when the TypeReference instance is compiled in this case, it a type reference to the real concrete class that we expect.

You could do the same thing passing in a Class at runtime, however TypeReference is a bit more powerful because it even works when type  T is a generic collection. There is some magic in the TypeReference implementation that allows it to hold onto type information that would normally be erased.

[update]

Updated to use `Collection<Person>`.  Note - as far as I know as `List<Whatever>` should work also, but I double checked a project where I was using jackson to deserialize collections. Base class Collection definitely worked so I stayed with that.

Comment: Ok i am starting to get this.. i made this work using a single object but i am unable to do it for a list. can you provide a bit more input on this? thanks for your effort so far.

Comment: OK i have made it work. similar to this but you proved a point. thanks a lot. The only thing i hate is that i have to send the .class and also define the generic parameter and i end up with something like new Parser<AlbumModel>(AlbumModel.class)

Answer (score 2):

Your type T will be "erased" at runtime, so Jackson does not know what is the real type of T and deserializes it to a Map. You need a second parameter to your parse method that will be `Class<T> clazz` or `TypeReference<T>` or `java.lang.reflect.Type`.

**EDIT**

Small explanation on the magic of TypeReference. When you do new XX() **{}** you are creating a anonymous class, so if it is a class with typevariables (parameterized if you prefer), new `X<List<Y>>() {},` you will be able to retrieve `List<Y>` as a java Type at runtime. It is very similar as if you had done :

```
abstract class MyGenericClass<T> {}
class MySpecializedClass extends MyGenericClass<List<Y>> {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Jackson you probably need to create a custom JsonDeserializer or JsonSerializer depending on whether you're handing the response or request. I've done this with Dates because on my response I want a standard view. I'm not 100% positive it will work with a generic field though.  Here is an example of what I'm doing:

```
public class DateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date> {

    private SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ");

    @Override
    public void serialize(Date value, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String dateString = dateFormat.format(value);
        jgen.writeString(dateString);
    }

}
```

Then I just add it to my class like so:

```
@JsonSerialize(using = DateSerializer.class)
public Date getModifiedDate() {
    return modifiedDate;
}
```