# Jackson read json in generic List

Tags: java, json, list, jackson

I'm using Jackson in order to read json messages. One of the values that I' trying to parse is a List and another value contains the type of the data in the list. This is the structure i 've created in java.

```
public class Message<T> {
   private Timestamp time;
   private RestAction action;
   private String type;
   private List<T> data;
}
```

Through `Class.forName();` I can get the class which represents the data in the list. The question is how can I read the List.

Comment: Can you show to us your example JSON string and source code which you have already written? I think you can also see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605524/jackson-delay-deserializing-field/17625688

Comment: If you don't mind please mark my answer which got most of the points as a valid one. It is compact and does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

If you need to map the incoming json to your List you can do like this

```
String jsonString = ...; //Your incoming json string
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Class<?> clz = Class.forName(yourTypeString);
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class, clz);
List <T> result = mapper.readValue(jsonString, type);
```

**Edit**

Something like this, completly untested and never done

```
public Message<T> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext arg1)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    ObjectCodec oc = jsonParser.getCodec();
    JsonNode node = oc.readTree(jsonParser);

    JsonNode timeStamp = node.get("time");
    Timestamp time = mapper.readValue(timeStamp, Timestamp.class);
    JsonNode restAction = node.get("action");
    RestAction action = mapper.readValue(restAction, RestAction.class);
    String type = node.get("type").getTextValue();
    Class<?> clz = Class.forName(type);
    JsonNode list = node.get("data");
    JavaType listType = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(List.class,   clz);
    List <T> data = mapper.readValue(list, listType);

    Message<T> message = new Message<T>;
    message.setTime(time);
    message.setAction(action);
    message.setType(type);
    message.setData(data);

    return message;
}
```

Comment: Ok...I already tried to solve it like this but the problem is that th json message has other fields in addition to the list.

Comment: Oops my bad, I didn't understand your question. Then you need to create a deserializer like seralex.vi said. You can use something like this inside it to deserialize the List

Comment: Edited my answer, let me know if it works, I'll probably have to do something similar soon

Comment: thnx for the answer...actually combining your answer and seralex's one helped me solve it (writing something similar to your edited answer). No opportunity to try it because of other problems but I think this part is done. Thnx again!

Answer (score 103):

Something which is much shorter:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<EntryType>>() {});
```

Where `EntryType` is a reference to type you would like to hold within collection. It might be any Java class.
For example to read JSON representation such as `["a", "b", "c"]`  second argument to mapper should be `new TypeReference<List<String>>() {}`

Comment: It works. Also try this:    Iterator<Objects> it = mapper.reader(Objects.class).readValues(in);

Comment: Where Objects.class comes from?

Comment: It belongs to the type which is on the list (EntryType on your example)

Comment: This answer does not clarify where `EntryType` comes from!

Comment: This does not answer the question, which specifically says to "read json in generic list". If you were to use this code, by replacing `EntryType` with generic type `T`, you will get the error: `java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to ...` 

(For more information, refer to this article: https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-linkedhashmap-cannot-be-cast)

The correct solution is [the accepted answer by alex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17979806/9171260), which has less upvotes than this answer.

Comment: Look carefully at comment below code "EntryType is a reference to type you would like to hold within collection". I had a look on article which you have linked, I found there very similar way which rely on `TypeReference`. The accepted answer by alex gives you bunch of code which you need to maintain for no reason as Jackson is capable of handling this using reflection API.

Answer (score 10):

Since version 2.11 (Apr 2020) Jackson has `readerForListOf` method ([documentation](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readerForListOf-java.lang.Class-)):

```
ObjectMapper mapper = ObjectMapper().configure(...);
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerForListOf(MyClass.class);
List<MyClass> list = reader.readValue(...);
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to annotate your class with `@JsonDeserialize(using = MessageDeserializer.class)` and implement custom deserializer:

```
public class MessageDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Message> {
  @Override
  public Message deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser, DeserializationContext deserializationContext)
    throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
    // YOU DESERIALIZER CODE HERE
  }
}
```

@see examples here: [How Do I Write a Jackson JSON Serializer & Deserializer?](http://dev.sghill.net/2012/04/how-do-i-write-jackson-json-serializer.html)

Answer (score 0):

This should work for simple POJO and Collections:

```java
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
// import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

// get your <T> type
final Type entryType = ...

// Create a new TypeReference object and convert
return new ObjectMapper().readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<>() {
    @Override
    public Type getType() {
        return entryType;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

If you need to read json in generic List, 
Do something like

```
{
    Employee:
    [
        {
            "key": "value",
            "key": "value"
        },
        {
            "key": "value",
            "key": "value"
        }
    ]
}
```

your json list object
and 
your bean class is

```
class person {
private String key;
private String value;
}
```

now you can read this json using HashMap

something like

```
TypeReference<HashMap<String,List<Person>>> personList =  new   TypeReference<HashMap<String, List<Person>>>() {};

ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

HashMap<String, List<Person>> employees = objectMapper.readValue(request.getInputStream(), personList);
```