# Incompatible types for generic

Tags: java, generics, jackson

I define jackoson serializer and add it to java class as JsonDeserialize like this:

```
@JsonDeserialize(using = ReportFilterDeserializer.class)
```

The compiler give this error:

```
error: incompatible types: Class<ReportFilterDeserializer> cannot be converted to Class<? extends JsonDeserializer<?>>
@JsonDeserialize(using = ReportFilterDeserializer.class)
```

The def of the annotation is:

```
public Class<? extends JsonDeserializer<?>> using() default JsonDeserializer.None.class;
```

If I remove the generic atttibute from ReportFilterDeserializer its passed compilation. I dont understand why the complier complain.

```
class ReportFilterDeserializer<T> extends JsonDeserializer<ReportFilter<T>> {
    @Override
    public ReportFilter<T> deserialize(JsonParser jsonParser,DeserializationContext arg1) throws IOException,JsonProcessingException {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: How the declaration code for this serialized object look like?

Comment: How do you plan on implementing `deserialize`? How do you determine the `T` within the JSON?

Comment: You can look on this one:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17979346/jackson-read-json-in-generic-list

this is how i implement. This question is on the generic , so lets put aside the json isssue.

Comment: @MaxZoom the declaration is in the question - look on the using def :

Answer (score 1):

That certainly seems very odd. About the only thing I can think of is accidental mixing of Jackson 1.x and 2.x annotation vs classes (org.codehaus.jackson is 1.x, com.fasterxml.jackson 2.x).

Does behavior differ on different JDKs (7 vs 8, for example -- maybe Java 8 has issues?)

Comment: Its java 8 and i break it to separate class and wanst success:
@Target({ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Test
{
    public Class<? extends JsonDeserializer<?>> using()
        default JsonDeserializer.None.class;
}

Comment: All I can say is that this looks more like a Java 8 bug than something Jackson does. :-(

Comment: ... especially since that code compiles ok on Java 7.

Comment: For what it is worth, it seems possible to work around the issue for Jackson 2.6 (see issue https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/issues/812), but unfortunately signature change can not be made for older versions. I think `javac` is wrong here, but the work-around is indeed to avoid generic deserializer/serializers: you need to use concrete type. If necessary, by simple sub-classing.