# How to (completely) deserialize json into a generic List?

Tags: java, generics, jackson, json-deserialization

When using an `ObjectMapper` to transform a json `String` into an entity, I can make it generic as:

```
public <E> E getConvertedAs(String body, Class<E> type) throws IOException {
    return mapper.readValue(body, type);
}
```

Now let's say I want to read collections. I can do:

```
List<SomeEntity> someEntityList = asList(mapper.readValue(body, SomeEntity[].class));
List<SomeOtherEntity> someOtherEntityList = asList(mapper.readValue(body, SomeOtherEntity[].class));
```

I would like to write an equivalent method of the above, but for collections. Since you can't have generic arrays in java, something like this won't work:

```
public <E> List<E> getConvertedListAs(String body, Class<E> type) {
    return mapper.readValue(body, type[].class);
}
```

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20398614/5961990) there is a solution that almost works:

```
mapper.readValue(jsonString, new TypeReference<List<EntryType>>() {});
```

The problem is that it doesn't deserialize into a list of `E`, but of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`. Is there any way of going going a step further, something like the following?

```
public <E> List<E> getConvertedListAs(String body, Class<E> type) {
    mapper.readValue(body, new TypeReference<List<type>>() {}); // Doesn't compile
}
```

Comment: Maybe `new TypeReference<List<E>>() {}` ?

Comment: @JeremyGrand `E` is my `EntryType`, that's what gives me the list of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This method can help to read `json` to an object or collections:

```
public class JsonUtil {
    private static final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public static <T>T toObject(String json, TypeReference<T> typeRef){
        T t = null;
        try {
            t = mapper.readValue(json, typeRef);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Read json to list:

```
List<Device> devices= JsonUtil.toObject(jsonString,
                            new TypeReference<List<Device>>() {});
```

Read json to object:

```
Device device= JsonUtil.toObject(jsonString,
                                new TypeReference<Device>() {});
```

Comment: What is ObjectMapper?  Is that a in an Import library?  I get all kinds of errors on that one.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static <E> List<E> fromJson(String in_string, Class<E> in_type) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException{
    return new ObjectMapper().readValue(in_string, new TypeReference<List<E>>() {});
}
```

Compiles on my computer.
Note that I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: Please see my reply to your comment. It compiles, but returns a list of `LinkedHashMap.Entry`