# Java Jackson: JSON value unknown

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm still learning how to use Jackson...

So I have a JSON object that has a value that sometimes is an Integer, a long String, or a List

Value: Integer

```
{
  "id":1,
  "active":1,
  "name":"name1",
  "value":155,
  ...
```

Value: String

```
{
  "id":2,
  "active":1,
  "name":"name2",
  "value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book...",
  ...
```

Value: List

```
{
  "id":3,
  "active":1,
  "name":"name3",
  "value":[
    "One",
    "Two",
    "Three",
    "Four"],
  ...
```

So all together it looks like...

```
{
  {
      "id":1,
      "active":1,
      "name":"name1",
      "value":155,
      ...
  },
  {
      "id":2,
      "active":1,
      "name":"name2",
      "value":"Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book...",
      ...
  },
  {
      "id":3,
      "active":1,
      "name":"name3",
      "value":[
        "One",
        "Two",
        "Three",
        "Four"],
      ...
  }
}
```

Here my POJO Model

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class OQScoresRows {
  private int id;
  private int active;
  private String name;
  private List<String> value;
  ... ...
```

Here's my mapper code

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
try{
  POJO obj = mapper.readValue(<JSONOBJECT>, POJO.class);
}catch(JsonParseException e){
  return mapper.writeValueAsString(e);
}
```

The problem is when I execute my code, I get the following error:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_NUMBER_INT token
```

It's clear to me that this is happening because "value" can contain one of three different types, how do I make my code flexible enough to accommodate the types...I can always in other methods detect if the value is an int, List, or String but I first need to model (don't I)...

My question is simple: how do I make my code flexible enough to accommodate the types...

Comment: Use List<String> and while de-serialising, check if the list contains only 1 element or more. If it contains only 1 element, try and parse it to long or int. If that fails, it's a String. Of course , it's not a good approach and maybe instead of having 1 values field you should have 4 and use jsonignoreproperties while de-serialising

Comment: First of all, you need to treat single value as array, you may do that by configuring `ObjectMapper` - `objectMapper.enable(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY);`
Then, you want to treat `int` as `String`, you may do that with annotation:

`@JsonDeserialize(using = StringDeserializer.class, as = String.class) private List<String> value;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it can be either of `Integer`, `List` and `String` then you can declare it as an `Object` and cast it later with `instanceof`, e.g.:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown=true)
@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility= JsonAutoDetect.Visibility.ANY)
public class OQScoresRows {
  private int id;
  private int active;
  private String name;
  private Object value;
```

After, deserializeing, you can write similar logic to the following:

```
if(value instanceof Integer){
    //do something after casting it to Integer
}else if(value instanceof List){
    //do something after casting it to List
}else if(value instanceof String){
    do something after casting it to String
}
```

Comment: Ok - so that makes semi-sense to me...what do you mean by "deserialise it later..."? when does later occur? I apologize, I know it's not proper etiquette to ask for code, but I'm trying to get a sense of what you mean exactly by "later"

Comment: Okay, so which part does not make sense then?

Comment: I do not see the changes/updates that you made in you answer...Also, my question is simply, where would that block of if statements go? In the Model class or after I read in the JSON object via the mapper?

Comment: @DidierJeanCharles I changed the description from "deserialise it later" to "cast it later..". This block of code should be executed _after_ deserialisation, when you need to access the `value`.

Answer (score 1):

`If-else` statement is fine for your question, but it's all string format in json objects, so you have to figure out a way to identity data types from values. For example, `Integer.valueOf(value)` to identity int; start with `[` to identity list; another is string type. You can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947213/how-to-completely-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-list/42947419#42947419), which is a general way to convert the json string to an object or a list.