# i want to get size of multiple Json object array using Jackson object Mapper.how can i get this without using Jackson tree

Tags: java, spring, jackson

```
<b>Here is Json:</b>

[{"index":"incident","type":"SmbIncident"},
{"index":"incident","type":"SmbIncident"}
]


IndexPortion is class how can i get both Json object size.
```

IndexPortion= new ObjectMapper().readValue(new File(path), 
   IndexPortion.class);

Answer (score 0):

First you should create an entity for the json object:

```
public class MyEntity implements Serializable{
    private String index;
    private String type;
    // getter and setter
}
```

Then you can convert the json array to list with the JsonUtil [from this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947213/how-to-completely-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-list/42947419#42947419):

```
List<MyEntity> entities= JsonUtil.toObject(jsonString,
                            new TypeReference<List<MyEntity>>() {});
int size = entities.size();
```