# Convert Json to Google Datastore Entity

Tags: java, json, android-studio, google-cloud-datastore

I've been developing a Java app on android studio and I want to extract a couple entities I stored in google datastore. The entities were stored as `List<Entity>` and converted to Json. In Android studio I'm now struggling to convert the Stringified Entities back to their original version. Here is an example of my Json response:

```
[{"properties":
              {"name":
                     {"valueType":"STRING", "values":"nameOfEntity", ...},
               "date":
                     {"valueType":"STRING", "values":"dateOfEntity", ...},
               ...
              }
}]
```

I only need the "values" of each one of the properties.

Is there any way to convert the response back to a Datastore Entity with json?

EDIT:
A snippet of my code

```
 public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> r) {
            if(r.isSuccessful()) {
                try {
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                        List<String> values = null;
                        Gson gson = new Gson();
                        JSONArray array = new JSONArray(r.body().string());

                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(i);
                        String properties = obj.getString("properties");

                        JSONArray array2 = new JSONArray(properties);

                        for (int j = 0; j < array2.length(); j++) {
                            JSONObject obj2 = array2.getJSONObject(j);
                            values.add(obj2.getString("values"));
                        }

                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "FINISHED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

Comment: What library/version are you using? Could you post a snippet as you turn the object into JSON? I suggest adding details to your question to make it more reproducible. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm using retrofit2 and Java 1.8 with sdk 30, I will edit my post with the snipped of code!

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you'll need to use a Java deserialization library (like [`gson`](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#TOC-Overview)) to convert a JSON string to an equivalent Java Object.

It's possible but it can be a lengthy process to do so. An Entity Object is composed of many other objects, and you will have to rewrite each down since Cloud Client libraries currently don't support Android. There are also tutorials out there already with regards to deserialization. See this [link](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md#serializing-and-deserializing-generic-types) as an example.

Finally, I recommend that you review the entire structure of the object so you can get started. Check out the Datastore object [`Entity`](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/reference/data/rest/v1/Entity).

Comment: Ok, I see, so the problem here is the generic type? Since Cloud libraries don't support android should I try to send the Entities some other way to the datastore (instead of List<Entity> I can use List<EventData> and deserealize after)?

Comment: I can't find anything about `List<EventData>` so unfortunately, I can't answer that part of your question. However, it's possible to deserialize a JSON into a generic List. Common deserialization library used are Gson and Jackson. Please check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42947213/how-to-completely-deserialize-json-into-a-generic-list

Comment: I managed to do it by cycling through each value and fetching the value I want. To reduce the code I used the methods getProperties().values() of datastore Entity and send only the values of the properties instead of the whole thing.