# How can I read an embedded class with Jackson

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have the following JSON, which is a generic wrapper for Messages. From the subject I can determine what the contents are.

```
{
  "subject" : "P:WORKSPACE:ADDED",
  "msgType" : "FileInfo[]",
  "contents" : [ {
    "lastModified" : 1380552566000,
    "name" : "genSPI.vhd.pshdl",
    "size" : 630,
    "syntax" : "unknown",
    "type" : "pshdl"
  } ]
}
```

Now when I read the Object with an objectReader, the contents will be a generic ArrayList with embedded Maps as the objectReader does not know what to do with the contents. That is ok for me. But how can I create a class from the contents later on? I don't want to use the polymorphic feature of Jackson as the classes that Message can contain are not known statically.

The solution I found so far appears rather clumsy to me:

```java
final Object json = message.getContents();
final String jsonString = writer.writeValueAsString(json);
final FileInfo[] readValues = mapper.readValue(jsonString, FileInfo[].class);
```

Comment: Do you have mapping between "msgType" values and real classes? How do you know that "FileInfo" is a.b.c.FileInfo class but not x.y.z.FileInfo?

Comment: The msgType field is rather informative, then declarative. The true knowledge about the contents type comes from knowing the subject.

Comment: OK. So, you have mapping between subject values and real classes, don't you? See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605524/jackson-delay-deserializing-field/17625688#17625688. Maybe it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Hmm, I think that might actually be the solution. Thanks!

Comment: Great, let me know if you have any other question or problems. I'll try to help as much as I can.