# Determining type while deserializing JSON

Tags: java, json, jackson

I'm working on deserializing some content from the reddit API into POJOs. My goal is to simplify the code as much as possible, as the JSON structure between entities within reddit is typically the same.

As an example, JSON to deserialize a link object would look like this:

```
[
    {
        "kind": "Listing",
        "data": {
            "modhash": "",
            "children": [
                {
                    "kind": "t3",
                    "data": {
                        "title": "A sample link from reddit"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
]
```

I can deserialize this no problem, but since a reddit comment differs by having a `kind` of `t1` and a different structure within the `data` object below it, I'd like to reuse the same class structure for the JSON wrapping it instead of having to create multiple copied classes with a one or two line difference.

I created a blank interface, `RedditEntity`, and created a `RedditLink` class implementing it. My problem is I don't know how to tell Jackson what interface implementation to deserialize to. Normally I would use the `@JsonSubType` annotation, but that only works on members within the object, not on a member wrapping it. I also don't know of how to write a custom deserializer that would work on a similar level, where I can determine the type from a parent object.

My question is then, how could I deserialize the `data` object based upon the `kind` type above it?

Comment: Your looks similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17605524/jackson-delay-deserializing-field/17625688. Please, see my answer. I think you can reuse it to solve your problem.

Comment: @MichałZiober Your answer seems to rely on the fact that the top level in the JSON contains the type variable you're looking for, where my example does not (it's nested three levels down).

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to know the type above? Seems like this should work:

```
@JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, property = "kind")
@JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(RedditListing.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(RedditLink.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(RedditComment.class)})
public static interface RedditEntity {}

@JsonTypeName("Listing")
public static class RedditListing implements RedditEntity { ... }

@JsonTypeName("t1")
public static class RedditComment implements RedditEntity { ... }

@JsonTypeName("t3")
public static class RedditLink implements RedditEntity { ... }
```